# I can not import retrofit RestAdapter despite i dowloaded the jar file

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I dowloaded `retrofit:2.0.0-beta2`. 
I added to `build.gradle` file like compile (`'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'`) 
I can import retrofit classes expect `RestAdapter`.

How can I solve this problem?

```
import retrofit.Callback; 
import retrofit.Response;
import retrofit.Retrofit;
```

I can not

```
import retrofit.RestAdapter;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use the stable version of retrofit?

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
```

Comment: You are right.  I do it.

Comment: Ok, if everything is ok, please accept my answer. Thanks